# Dynamically render components in react based on conditions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a component to dynamically create a textbox based on button click

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Input = () => {
  return <input placeholder="Your input here" />;
};

const Form = () => {
  const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([]);

  const onAddBtnClick = (event) => {
    setInputList(inputList.concat(<Input key={inputList.length} />));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {inputList}
      <button onClick={onAddBtnClick}>Add input</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Form />, document.getElementById("form"));
```

So basically this loads a button on page load and create new textboxes everytime the "Add Input" button is clicked.

So sometimes, there can be scenarios like some values for textboxes are already available on pageload. In those cases, for example, if I have three values for TextBox available as a list **["Apple", "Mango", "Carrot"]**, then my page should have three TextBoxes created each with one of the values from the above list followed by the "Add Input" button

And If new textboxes are created, how to get the values of all the TextBox on button click.

Will this be possible to do in react.
Kindly guide me on how to approach this problem.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

```
your input handler function should look like this,
  const onAddBtnClick = (event) => {
    setInputList([...inputList,<Input key={inputList.length} />]);
  };

In this way you will get the previous input as well as your newly generated input element
```

Comment: thank you for replying.. how will i populate the components on page load. do you have any idea regarding that ?

Comment: You are pointing to page refresh right? if so you need to store state value to local storage and when page load you need to retrieve it from local storage.Coz when you load your page your state value vanishes and it starts from the initial point.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think it is, you just need to modify your `useState` to initialize the state with these values. And then, capture the values of all the text boxes when a button is clicked, so you can maintain a reference to each input element and update the state accordingly.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Input = ({ value, onChange }) => {
  return <input placeholder="Your input here" value={value} onChange={onChange} />;
};

const Form = () => {
  // Initial values for the text boxes
  const initialValues = ["Apple", "Mango", "Carrot"];

  // State to hold the current values of the text boxes
  const [inputList, setInputList] = useState(initialValues.map((val, index) => ({ value: val, id: index })));

  // Ref to hold references to the input elements
  const inputRefs = useRef([]);

  const onAddBtnClick = () => {
    // Add a new empty input field
    setInputList([...inputList, { value: "", id: inputList.length }]);
  };

  const onSubmit = () => {
    // Get the values of all the text boxes
    const values = inputList.map((input, index) => inputRefs.current[index].value);
    console.log(values); // Log the values to see them in the console
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {inputList.map((input, index) => (
        <Input
          key={input.id}
          value={input.value}
          ref={el => inputRefs.current[index] = el}
          onChange={e => setInputList(inputList.map((item, i) => i === index ? { ...item, value: e.target.value } : item))}
        />
      ))}
      <button onClick={onAddBtnClick}>Add input</button>
      <button onClick={onSubmit}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Form />, document.getElementById("form"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to solve this.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Input = (props) => {
  return <input {...props} placeholder="Your input here" />;
};

const Form = ({ data }) => {
  const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setInputList(
      data.map((item, i) => (
        <Input
          id={`input${i}`}
          name={`input${i}`}
          key={i}
          defaultValue={item}
        />
      ))
    );
  }, [data]);

  const onAddBtnClick = (event) => {
    setInputList(
      inputList.concat(
        <Input
          id={`input${inputList.length}`}
          name={`input${inputList.length}`}
          key={inputList.length}
        />
      )
    );
  };

  const onSubmit = () => {
    var form = document.getElementById("form");

    var formData = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) {
      var element = form.elements[i];
      if (element.tagName === "INPUT" && element.type !== "button") {
        formData[element.name] = element.value;
      }
    }

    console.log(formData);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {inputList}
      <button type="button" onClick={onAddBtnClick}>
        Add input
      </button>
      <button type="button" onClick={onSubmit}>
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Form data={["Apple", "Mango", "Carrot"]} />, document.getElementById("form"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to leave components out of states.

You can have the number of inputs inside your state and increment the state each time the button is clicked and just render inputs based on the count.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Input = () => {
  return <input placeholder="Your input here" />;
};

const Form = () => {
  const [inputsCount, setInputsCount] = useState(0);

  const onAddBtnClick = () => {
    setInputsCount((prevCount) => ++prevCount);
  };

  return (
    <div>
     {Array.from(Array(inputsCount).keys()).map((_, index) => (
       <Input key={index} />
      ))}
      <button onClick={onAddBtnClick}>Add input</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Form />, document.getElementById("form"));
```